# Why does my cron job sometimes fail on cd with "not a directory"?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, cd

I created a daily cron job on an unattended Ubuntu workstation:

```
0 3 * * * cd /home/spertus/src-mirror/blockly; svn up; git add -A; git commit -m "Automatic commit `date`"; git push
```

About half the time, it works.  The other half of the time, I am emailed an error message that starts with the following line:

```
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /home/spertus/src-mirror/blockly: Not a directory
Skipped '.'
```

Anyone know why cd would fail?

Comment: because sometimes the path is a file and not a directory

Comment: I'm the only person who has access, and I'm never changing that point in the file hierarchy, so I don't know how it could ever by a file.  BTW, I like your suffix.

Comment: Is your home directory automounted?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, that's probably it.  Sounds like I should move the directory somewhere else or get local advice on how to force it to be mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your home directory is automounted, which means that `/home/spertus` isn't going to exist if you haven't accessed it recently.

As you say in a comment, you should either move the directory somewhere else or find out how to force it to be mounted.

It's possible that just accessing your home directory before executing the command:

```
ls /home/spertus >/dev/null 2>&1; cd /home/spertus/src-mirror/blockly; ...
```

would be sufficient, but I don't know enough about automounting to be sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I bet moving (or re-creating) the directory (and making the corresponding change to the crontab) will fix the problem.  If it doesn't, I'll reopen the question.

Comment: `ls /home/spertus >/dev/null 2>&1; cd /home/spertus/src-mirror/blockly;` Won't that still execute the command for cd, since you are using `;`? You probably want to use `&&`

Comment: @ansh0l: Yes, and if the `cd` fails, you'll get an error message, which is exactly what should happen. The hope is that the `ls` command will cause `/home/spertus` to be automounted. I don't know whether it will actually work.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ok, I thought the `ls` was to check if the directory exists, only then `cd` into it. In any case, `ls` alone doesn't automount a directory on my system. Just curious, when can `ls` automount a directory?

Comment: @ansh0l: I don't know; as I said, I don't know much about automounting. The general idea is that the directory doesn't exist until you attempt to access it, but some ways of accessing it can still fail. The `ls` trick is a guess.